# Alter columns for each row in dataframe basing on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has got many columns.
I want to apply a function on each row that alters all the columns based on different column.

```
def mark(row):
  columns = get_columns_to_alter(row['Text'])
  for c in columns:
      row[c] = True
```

And I was trying to use apply function

```
 df.apply(mark, axis=1)
```

But it does not alter these columns. What am I doing wrong? The function I gave is a psuedocode but it gets names of columns to change basing on "Text" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
This is a bit confusing, to be honest.
Several issues I see:

**First**, `DataFrame.apply` a function to each column should look more like:

```
df.apply(lambda x: mark(x), axis=1)
```

so that you actually loop through each row.

**Second**, `DataFrame.apply` creates a copy Series for each row (in your case); thus, the changes are not applied to `df` but to the new `row` value. If you want to change `df`, you need to (a) make sure that `mark` returns something and (b) to assign it to something else:

```
def mark(row):
  columns = get_columns_to_alter(row['Text'])
  if len(columns) > 0:
    row[columns] = True
  return row

new_df = df.apply(lambda x: mark(x), axis=1)
```

Something like this should do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is it a proper approach? Do people do it this way? For me it would be easier to use regular dicts and do everything in pure python. Is it worth to use Pandas and dataframes ?

Comment: well... my guess is that it all depends on the amount of data you are going to use. For small stuff, I would say you can easily go with standard python, but as your data gets bigger, the more useful pandas become. What I can say is that pandas is a library worth to become familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution via `numpy` and `itertools.chain`. As far as possible, it's a good idea to remove loops.

```
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, (10, 10)))
df['cols'] = [np.random.randint(0, 9, 3) for _ in df]

def calc_cols(s):

    arr = s.values.tolist()

    # apply function on arr here, e.g.
    # arr = list(map(f, arr))

    idx = np.repeat(list(range(len(arr))), list(map(len, arr)))

    return idx, list(chain(*arr))

A, cols = df.values, calc_cols(df['cols'])

A[cols[0], cols[1]] = -1

df_res = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=df.columns)

#     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  9       cols
# 0   2   4  -1   4  -1   2   6   6   8  1  [4, 4, 2]
# 1   4  -1  -1   3   4   4  -1   5   6  7  [2, 1, 6]
# 2  -1   1   7   1   2  -1   2   2  -1  0  [8, 0, 5]
# 3   2   4  -1   6  -1   8   6  -1   0  3  [7, 2, 4]
# 4  -1   5   5   2   8   2  -1   8  -1  6  [8, 6, 0]
# 5   5   6   0   3   5  -1  -1   5   3  7  [6, 5, 6]
# 6  -1   0   7   1   4  -1  -1   6   1  8  [5, 6, 0]
# 7   2   6   4   6  -1   6  -1   5   7  6  [6, 4, 6]
# 8  -1   8   1  -1   0   7   8  -1   2  3  [3, 0, 7]
# 9   2   4   6   6  -1  -1   0   2  -1  0  [4, 8, 5]
```